# Regular expression for only matching an end parenthesis ")" when atleast two words come prior?

Tags: regex

I figured a lookbehind of only matching ")" when it's part of "(any-*set*-of-words)" would do the trick, but it turns out quantifiers like "+" can't be used in either type of lookbehind. So how do people accomplish this? I just want the regex to skip "(any-*single*-word)" and notice "(any-*set*-of-words)".

> (Insert entire sentence full of words and potentially containing an additional (parenthesized word or set of words).)

The program (TextAloud 4) should match both of the ")"'s.

> (Junior)

The program *shouldn't* match the ")".

The closest I've gotten to making this work is below, but it only notices "(character/word character)".

```
(?<=\S(?:\s[A-Za-z0-9]))\)
```

My positive lookahead is set to match any "(" that comes immediately before "(any-*set*-of-words)" and works just fine. I'm aware that it'll also match "(a d)", but don't expect it to be a problem as this is primarily for converting a webnovel into a personal audiobook.

```
\((?=[A-Za-z0-9!?]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z0-9]+))
```

The end goal is to have TA4 1) say "Open parenthesis. Yeah, I am. Close parenthesis" for "(Yeah, I am.)" and 2) say "Makoto" for "(Makoto)".

Answer (score 0):

This string matches the end parenthesis only if there are two alphanumeric groups before it seperated by a space of hyphen.

```
([a-zA-z0-9!?.]+[ \-]+[a-zA-z0-9!?.]+\s?)(\))
```

matches the parenthesis at the end of `set of words).)` and `(TextAloud 4)`
but not the one at the end of `(Junior)`
it also accepts a space between the second word and the parenthesis as in `two words )`
We can do partiel replacement by using $1, $2 etc to refer to the parentheses is the regex.
Here is an example in PHP:

```php
$testStrings="(Hello mate)<br>(Julien)<br>(What-are-you-doing?)<br>";
$pattern = "/([a-zA-z0-9!?.]+[ \-]+[a-zA-z0-9!?.]+\s?)(\))/";

print(preg_replace($pattern,"$1",$testStrings));
/* prints
(Hello mate
(Julien)
(What-are-you-doing?
*/
print(preg_replace($pattern,"$2",$testStrings));
/* prints
()
(Julien)
(What-are-)
*/
```

which leads to a possible solution for your need:

```
print(preg_replace($pattern,"$1 - closing parenthesis",$testStrings));
/* prints
(Hello mate - closing parenthesis
(Julien)
(What-are-you-doing? - closing parenthesis
/*
```

We haven't dealt with the opening partenthesis, but the same method should work.

Comment: Thanks. This gets me closer. 
Since it's consuming the previous two sets of characters, it prevents TA from reading aloud the whole text. Can it be converted to something non-capturing? (edits incoming)  
edit: I added `!?.` to it so it'll work with sentences too. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/k4JwYU/1)'s the regex101 link.